# In Postgres, how can I delete a row from table B when a row from table A is deleted?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-delete, cascade

I’m using Postgres 9.5.0.  I have the following table

```
myproject=> \d my_objects;
                                  Table "public.my_objects"
       Column        |            Type             |              Modifiers              
---------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------
 name                | character varying           | 
 day                 | date                        | 
 distance            | double precision            | 
 user_id             | integer                     | 
 created_at          | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at          | timestamp without time zone | not null
 distance_unit_id    | integer                     | 
 import_completed    | boolean                     | 
 id                  | character varying           | not null default uuid_generate_v4()
 linked_my_object_time_id | character varying           | 
 web_crawler_id      | integer                     | 
 address_id          | character varying           | 
Indexes:
    "my_objects_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_my_objects_on_user_id_and_day_and_name" UNIQUE, btree (user_id, day, name)
    "index_my_objects_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
    "index_my_objects_on_web_crawler_id" btree (web_crawler_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_5287d445c0" FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES addresses(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "fk_rails_970b2325bf" FOREIGN KEY (distance_unit_id) REFERENCES distance_units(id)
    "fk_rails_dda3297b57" FOREIGN KEY (linked_my_object_time_id) REFERENCES my_object_times(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "fk_rails_ebd32625bc" FOREIGN KEY (web_crawler_id) REFERENCES web_crawlers(id)
    "fk_rails_fa07601dff" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Right now, each my_object has an address field.  What I would like is when I delete the my_object, the corresponding address entry be deleted as well.  Without moving the address_id column out of the my_objects table, is it possible to set something up such that when I delete a row from the my_objects table, any corresponding address data is deleted as well?  Obviously, the foreign key I have set up will not get the job done.

Comment: If that is the case, why not include the address itself in the table `my_objects`?

Comment: What if there is more than one `my_objects` entry referencing the same `adresses` entry?

Comment: There is only one my_object per address.  I would include addresses in the my_objects table, but there are other types of objects taht use addresses (users, events, etc.) so I figured it would look a little cleaner if all the addresses were in one place.

Comment: @Dave But then, how do you know if a user or event doesn't use the same address?

Comment: Because I took the blue pill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_address() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   DELETE FROM public.addresses WHERE id = OLD.address_id;
   RETURN OLD;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER remove_address
   AFTER DELETE ON public.my_objects FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE remove_address()
```

Comment: "EXECUTE TRIGGER" produced some syntax errors, but "EXECUTE PROCEDURE" worked.

Comment: Should be fixed now.